# Добавить картинку для ImageButton

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

В моем приложении под Андроид имеется текстовое поле для ввода E-Mail'а пользователя, а также кнопка для просмотра дополнительной информации на сайте.  Кнопка должна активировать выпадающую информацию. Выглядеть должно вот так:
[image: кнопка с изображением стрелки] 
Кнопка реализуется с помощью ImageButton. В свойствах я нашел, что ей можно добавить одну из встроенных картинок вот так:`app:srcCompat="?android:attr/findOnPageNextDrawable"`
Проблема в том, что при попытки отладки приложения возникает следующая ошибка: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html

Comment: Там сказано, что данный атрибут не имеет публичного доступа, то есть вы его не можете использовать. Вместо этого вы можете прикрепить таким способом свою собственную картинку

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо, разъяснили. Буду знать.